# ISSUE IN EQUATIONS

Tags: math, equation, calculation, accounting

I have to find out margin profit from some values, but in many of the cases profit coming as negative value based on the calculating values. How can I adjust the variables to keep profit always positive value

```
1)  GoGet = (Go / 100) * (Get / 100) 

 2)  monthly system fee = monthly system fee* GoGet) / 100

 3)  monthly service fee = (monthly service fee * GoGet) / 100

4)   up front fee = (up front fee/ up front months) * (GoGet / 100)

5)   total month fee = up front fee + monthly system fee + monthly service fee
6)   gross profit margin=   total month fee - (cost of sale + (staff_costa * 
    service_months))
```

In the 6th equation is the issue, it will turn into a negative value, but the
profit cannot be negative.

Comment: what makes you think that profit should always be positive? you probably confuse it with cost

Comment: @mangusta somehow i have to keep profit always positive

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about accounting, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely mathematical point of view, the answer is to take the absolute value (or modulus) of gross_profit_margin.

However, as @mangusta points out, there's no reason that profit will always be positive. Can you provide more information as to why you *have* to keep profit positive?